# Laravel-Vue site slow

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed

https://www.torah.media/ is my site which loads really slow. The open-source project (https://github.com/phanan/koel) I've built https://www.torah.media/ on works really fast on their demo http://demo.koel.phanan.net/#!/home.

Please help figure out how can solve the speed issue for it. I can't seem to understand anything from the Chrome Network tab.

I've already tried switching from AWS to Cloudflare, still not much improvement in speed.

Comment: Not hard to figure out why. Your api response on page load is H U G E. I mean, you gave me 7000 songs, among other things. You could really leverage some caching here and pagination is your friend.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks for taking the time to look! Can you please as an answer tell me some ways I can get this speed down by leveraging caching? I am not an expert at that. And how can I use pagination in SPA to get that API response correctly, so that my site loads fast.

Comment: I think this question is way too broad. I am sure there are lots of examples you can search for online on how to add pagination in a Vue SPA. As for pagination in Laravel, they have a whole documentation page dedicated to it: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination

Comment: @NathanHeffley Thanks, and please add a comment about how to leverage caching and where can I learn how to do it for my case?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache

Answer (score 0):

Example of a cache response below.

```
    $people = Cache::remember('example:people', $ten_minutes_in_seconds, function () {
        $people = People::all();

        return $people;
    });

    return response()->json([
        'people' => $people,
    ], 200);
```

This may be cached but please to god be careful, e.g. never cache personal data relating to the user and also use pagination.